# AWS EC2 expose port 5000

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install KafkaMagic on ec2 to manage our kafka cluster.  I created an EC2 instance on our VPC and added the following inbound rules to the associated security group:

[image]

I then made sure the Network ACL had inbound rules to allow traffic

[image]

Where I saw that * is a catch all rule so rule 100 should overwrite this.  I then connected to my ec2 instance using EC2 Instance Connect and downloaded KafkaMagic and got it running on localhost:5000 of my ec2 instance.  Using the public dns for the ec2 instance i connected to {publicIp}:5000 where publicIp was copy pasted.  I was unable to connect.

Im assuming there is a gap in my understanding of what happened.  Where did I go wrong along the way setting this up? Im very new to AWS and I might be missing an important concept

Comment: Your Network ACLs and SG rules are fine by the way, so the issue is not there. "Using the public dns for the ec2 instance i connected to {publicIp}:5000 where publicIp was copy pasted" what do you mean by "connected" and also what do you mean by "publicip was copy pasted"?

Comment: @Riz I have the public ip associated with my ec2 instance that I copied into a url and hit port 5000 for that public ip.   I have actually since resolved the issue and am posting an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to run the application on a non localhost url.  I updated the kafka magic url through this link: https://www.kafkamagic.com/download/#configuration to be on 0.0.0.0:5000 and then I was able to use the public ip associated with my instance to run the application on port 5000